# Print Python long output to Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, printing

[image]I am struggling with apparently an easy problem..
I am printing an output in python( which is ok) but then I also want to save it in a DataFrame but no success there...
My code is here

```
#print(text_field[0].text)
#(This print the attached output)

DF=text_field[0].text
#Now trying to save the output in Dataframe
final=pd.DataFrame(DF, columns="Beskrivning")[![enter image description here][1]][1]

print(final)
```

Comment: any answer from anyone out there?